# Multidimensional Data MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Can somebody please tell me what multidimensional data means? I need tom consume data from a Data Cube [SSAS] MDX Query and populate it in a win form, any know hows?

Dinesh

Comment: look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456661/sample-mdx-queries/18298672#18298672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading a quick tutorial to MDX : [Gentle introduction to MDX](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html)

After you'll need a library to access your OLAP server (In Java [Olap4J](http://www.olap4j.org/), in .NET you've [ADOMD](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23089))

Comment: Thank you, that should help me get a move on :)

Comment: To others who are looking to use ADOMD.NET, you can get the Feature Pack that carries the ADOMD.NET Package Files [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=228DE03F-3B5A-428A-923F-58A033D316E1&displaylang=en ) The dll will be under the C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\100 folder